# Excel SUMIF add Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, sumifs

I am using this formula for SUMIF which is working fine, but I need to add another criteria which is the DATE. I only want the jobs to sum total if the date is the same in column A. How do I accomplish this?  When I use SUMIFS I get an error "too few arguments".[image]

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$786,I2,$F$2:$F$786)
```

Comment: You want a `=SUMIFS()` then:  `=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$786, $B$2:$B$786, I2, $A$2:$A$786, today())`

Comment: Remember that SUMIFS order is different.  `=SUMIFS(COLUMN_TO_SUM,CRIT_RANGE_1,CRIT_1,CRIT_RANGE_2,CRIT_2,...)`

Comment: The parameter list is different in a SUMIFS from a SUMIF. SUMIF has the option to either use the summing column for criteria or another column for criteria. SUMIFS always has both. Look up the difference at support.office.com.

Answer (score 4):

### Setting the Stage

When making my initial response, I didn't notice that the OP's sample data included two separate data ranges. There is the main "table" with columns including `DATETIME`, `PRODUCT` and `AVG CYCLE MINUTES`. These are the data to be summed across. However, the sums are not to appear against these rows, but against the rows in the second "table" which has the column `REFERENCE LIST`. `REFERENCE LIST` matches with the `PRODUCT` column in the first table and so provides one of the criteria for the SUMIF(S). The second criteria was to be `DATE`. However, since the second table doesn't include a date column it isn't  obvious where this should come from.

In discussion with the OP, we realised that we wanted a the total (or, as it turned out, average) of "AVG CYCLE MINUTES" for each combination of DATETIME and PRODUCT. I walked the OP through the process of creating a PivotTable to do this.

### Options

If we want to achieve the same or similar by means of SUMIF or SUMIFS, we need to make a decision about the DATE criteria. Either (a) the second table needs to include dates as well as `PRODUCT`s, or (b) we need to find a way to pick the date we're interested in.

**Sum for Every Combination of DATE and PRODUCT**

For option (a), an answer similar to my original one would work:

`=SUMIFS(F:F,B:B,I2,A:A,J2)`

where column J is the new column of dates. The full list of date/product combinations could have been swiftly produced by copying the relevant columns of the main data to elsewhere and using Excel's "remove duplicates" functionality.

**Sum for single DATE per PRODUCT**

For option (b), if you wanted to sum up all the data relating to "today", that could be done using:

`=SUMIFS(F:F, B:B, I2, A:A, today())`

(with credit to @JNevill).

What else might we want? Perhaps the most recent date the PRODUCT appears against? Or the earliest? If you have EXCEL 2016 (or better) ...

`=SUMIFS(F:F, B:B, I2, A:A, MAXIFS(A:A,B:B,I2))`

This would give the total minutes for the relevant PRODUCT on the latest date recorded for that PRODUCT. For the earliest date replace `MAXIFS` with `MINIFS`.

Alternatively, if the data is sorted so that the date you want will be the first to appear against any given `PRODUCT` you can use:

`=SUMIFS(F:F, B:B, I2, A:A, INDEX(A:A,MATCH(I2,I:I,0)))`

**Miscellanea**

I'd normally use `VLOOKUP` rather than `INDEX/MATCH` (a habit I've yet to acquire), but in the current data structure the columns are in the wrong order for that.

Since further discussion revealed that the OP actually wanted averages not totals, it's worth noting the existence of `AVERAGEIFS`.

*NOTE*: in my original answer (below), I reference the exact ranges rather than entire columns. There may be some marginal performance loss doing things as above, but I've never noticed. Though you need to be sure there are no extra data beneath the stuff you're interested in. On the other hand, there are definite benefits, it's easier to enter the formula and it will not need amending for larger (or smaller) data sets. (Thanks for reminding me of this @Jeeped)

*NOTE 2*: Since there is there is nothing you can do with SUMIF that can't also be done with SUMIFS, there is no harm in using the latter even when the former would suffice. That way you only have one function to remember and it's the most useful one. (Another good idea from @Jeeped)

### Original Answer

As others have said, I think you want `SUMIFS`. Here the `sum_range` comes to the front, and you follow that with pairs of "criteria range"s and "criteria" like this:

`=SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)`

In your case, I think that means you want:

`=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$786,$B$2:$B$786,I2,$A$2:$A$786,A2)`

When I wrote this, the relevant Microsoft Support page was [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: fwiw, I find it convenient to completely forget that SUMIF even exists and use SUMIFS for everything. At least 90% of any conditional sum formula that I need has more than a single parameter anyways and it really isn't a lot of extra typing to use SUMIFS for a single parameter.

Comment: fwiw² - full column references can be used in SUMIF and SUMIFS without unnecessary calculation cycles (as long as there aren't irrelevant numbers below that could cause false results).

Comment: @Steve Lovell  This is really odd, when I use your formula it works until I get to the 12th row and then just stops calculating. I think when it detects a duplicate job it fails so the total time is 00:00:00

Comment: I'm guessing in the dark here, but is it possible the figure is 24 hours (or a multiple of it?) You may want to check the way the cells are formatted.

Comment: Alternatively, since the job criteria is in column `I` but is looked for in the `B` column, it's possible not to match anything. Formatting and trailing spaces could be worth checking there too.

Comment: I find myself wondering, about the date criteria also. When you say you are matching the date, clearly one end of that comparison is the `A` column across all the rows. I've assumed the other end to be the `A` column on the current row, but that might not be right.  Your screenshot looks like two independent data areas, but then what date to compare?

Comment: That is sort of what I was just thinking. I will have the same job pairs running two or three times per month and the data will usually be in monthly buckets. I need the sum of the jobs as long as they are found on the same date so they do not get combined.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142542/discussion-between-steve-lovell-and-noob2java).

Comment: I may not have asked this clearly enough yesterday as I am getting different results with formulas I am trying. I got plenty of help from Steve Lovell thankfully that took me in another direction.  I would like to solve this formula for "SUMIFS".  What I have is pairs of jobs for any given day where I need to SUM the pairs as long as they show up together on the same day which gives me my total run time.  The formula works but I have to specify the date. So JOB-123, sum the pair that shows up together on any day then SUM the next pair and so on and so on.

Comment: Can someone help on this?

Comment: Not sure if you'll be automatically notified, so just in case ... I just submitted a bit update to my original answer.

Comment: Thank you @Steve Lovell this helps a lot. I had a separate question for you in the chat but I don't think it went through.

Comment: No worries. The question in chat arrived, but I doesn't notify me. Have responded there now.